# Cannot send UDP packets from development machine to Android Emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, udp

Because the Android Emulator does not support Multicast as described [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#limitations) I've been trying to make a work around for my situation.

To do this I wrote a small Java program which listens for Multicast packets and then repeats it to the localhost address. Because this 'Multicast repeater' is running on that same machine as the android Emulator, I was hoping I could loopback the Multicast packets into the Emulator. Unfortunately this does not seem to work.

This is my 'Multicast repeater' method which I run outside of Eclipse and the Emulator. I have checked that it receives UDP messages from another machine elsewhere on the network that transmits UDP packets containing the time:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        boolean loop = true;
        MulticastSocket socket = new MulticastSocket(4446);
        InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName("230.0.0.1");
    socket.joinGroup(address);
        DatagramSocket txSocket = new DatagramSocket();   // UDP socket to re transmit on
        DatagramPacket packet;
        while (loop){
        byte[] buf = new byte[256];
            packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);
            socket.receive(packet);

            String received = new String(packet.getData(), 0, packet.getLength());
            System.out.println("Quote of the Moment: " + received);
            packet = new DatagramPacket(received.getBytes(), received.getBytes().length, InetAddress.getLocalHost, 4448);
            txSocket.send(packet);
    }

    socket.leaveGroup(address);
    socket.close();
    }
```

And this is my 'receiver' code that runs in the android app:

```
ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) 
                getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
                txtView.append("Network connected.\r\n");
                WifiManager wm = (WifiManager)getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
                WifiManager.MulticastLock wmmc = wm.createMulticastLock("MulticastTest");
                if (wmmc.isHeld()){
                    txtView.append("Multicast lock is held\r\n");
                }else{
                    txtView.append("Multicast lock NOT held, attempting to acquire.\r\n");
                    wmmc.acquire();
                }
                if (wmmc.isHeld()){
                    try{
                        DatagramSocket rxSocket = new DatagramSocket(4448);
                        rxSocket.setSoTimeout(5000);
                        DatagramPacket packet;

                            // get a few quotes
                        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

                            byte[] buf = new byte[256];
                                packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);
                                try{
                                    rxSocket.receive(packet);
                                    String received = new String(packet.getData(), 0, packet.getLength());
                                    txtView.append(received + "\r\n");
                                } catch (InterruptedIOException ex){
                                    txtView.append("Socket timed out.\r\n");
                                }
                                //System.out.println("Quote of the Moment: " + received);
                        }

                        //socket.leaveGroup(address);
                        //socket.close();
                    }catch (Exception ex){
                        txtView.append(ex.toString() + "\r\n");
                    }finally{
                        wmmc.release();
                    }
                }else{
                    txtView.append("Could not acquire multicast lock.\r\n");
                }
            }else{
                txtView.append("Network NOT connected");
            }
```

Unfortunately the receive socket just times out. I have tried binding to '10.0.2.2' (described [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#networkaddresses)) but this throws an exception although this appears to be useful only if I wanted to access my development machine from the Emulator whereas I want to access the emulator from my development machine.
Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Reading further on the Emulator, it appears what I want to achieve is possible as described here: http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#redirection

Comment: The solution is the same as [here.][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2101505/642680

Comment: Did it work for you finally? I have been facing the same problem and it does not work with telnet redirect too. Please could you suggest something on my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57658867/udp-packets-not-received-in-emulator-from-localhost)

Comment: I recall it did but that was several years ago with an older Android Emulator. Are you saying port forwarding no longer works with the current emulator?

Comment: Thanks for your response. Port forwarding works for sure. Just that I was not able to see the UDP packets being received after trying all options including a telnet redirect. Thankfully, I was able to switch to TCP and it worked with an `adb reverse tcp:50000 tcp:50000`